# Correlating to list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join, correlation

I have two lists containing dictionaries:

```
List1 = [{"Value": "Value1", "Start": 7.11, "End": 8},
         {"Value": "Value2", "Start": 16.45, "End": 20}]

List2 = [{"From":7.11, "To": 8, "Result": 0},
         {"From":16.45, "To": 20 "Result": 1}
        ]
```

I need to produce a list by correlating these lists. So result will be

```
Result = [{"Value": "Value1", "Start": 7.11, "End": 8, Result: 0},
         {"Value": "Value2", "Start": 16.45, "End": 20,Result: 1}]
```

This almost seem like simple table join in SQL.

How would I do it in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: they guaranteed to be sorted in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
List1 = [{"Value": "Value1", "Start": 7.11, "End": 8},
 {"Value": "Value2", "Start": 16.45, "End": 20}]

List2 = [{"From":7.11, "To": 8, "Result": 0},
 {"From":16.45, "To": 20, "Result": 1}
]

new_list = [{**a, **{'Result':b['Result']}} for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'Value': 'Value1', 'Start': 7.11, 'End': 8, 'Result': 0}, {'Value': 'Value2', 'Start': 16.45, 'End': 20, 'Result': 1}]
```

Since, dictionary unpacking (`**`) is a feature in Python3 only, you can use `dict.items` in Python2:

```
new_list = [dict(a.items()+[('Result', b['Result'])]) for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'Start': 7.11, 'End': 8, 'Result': 0, 'Value': 'Value1'}, {'Start': 16.45, 'End': 20, 'Result': 1, 'Value': 'Value2'}]
```

Comment: Indeed! I am new to Python. Could you please explain what the code does?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @leon To create a paring between elements from each list, `zip` is used in a list comprehension. In the first version for Python3, the first pared dictionary is unpacked in to the new dictionary, and only the result value from the second paring is added. In the second example, unpacking is circumvented by creating nested lists and then applying `dict`.

Comment: Sorry, one more follow up question. How is correlation made ? In other words values for start and end keys in List1 matches with the same values for the same keys, so correct Result key/value is added.

Comment: @leon `zip` is a pairing between corresponding elements. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)